# How to show app icon on the Unlock Screen?

Tags: android

Someone asked me to insert any application icon on the screen before we unlock the screen. Is it possible to add an app icon like we add with the help of Widgets provided by the Android SDK?

Thanks in Advance,
Aagrah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, there is no official support for changing the lock screen in this fashion, though it has been discussed.

Comment: CommonsWare - can you please let me know what would be the approach to implement it like the one we have for WidgetLocker?

Comment: @Aagrah: That's not the OS lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Widget Locker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&feature=search_result) to customize your lock screen. In this screen it is possible to add widgets etc.